# Update Dynamic column values in Arango DB Update

Tags: arangodb, aql

Given the following document structure:

Input:

```
           LET A=status: 'free',updatedby:'SYSTEM',updatedate:'28/05/2021 12:15:34'
```

I want to update all column values in a single update.

find the given query:

```
           UPDATE { _key: @key }  WITH { A } IN Slot RETURN NEW
```

--here A is let value.

Is it possible?

Comment: What should your document look like after the update? Do I understand correctly that your document should be `{status: 'free', updatedby:'SYSTEM', updatedate:'28/05/2021 12:15:34', <...other fields unchanged>}`?

Comment: It has snowing error

Answer (score 1):

You can define an object and then use that to update an existing document by _key:

```
LET A = { status: 'free', updatedby: 'SYSTEM', updatedate: '28/05/2021 12:15:34' }
UPDATE @key WITH A IN Slot RETURN NEW
```

You can also inline the object:

```
UPDATE @key WITH { status: 'free', updatedby: 'SYSTEM', updatedate: '28/05/2021 12:15:34' } IN Slot RETURN NEW
```

Comment: Ok but my concern is need to pass the colum name in dynamic

Comment: Pass in how? As bind variable that is known at query compile time, or that is dynamically computed in the query? In the former case, you can do `RETURN { @name: 123 }` with the bind parameters `{ "name": "value" }` and the result will be `{ "value": 123 }`. In the latter case, you can use square brackets around the attribute name to interpret what is inside as expression instead of as unquoted string literal: `LET name = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_NOW(), "%hh:%ii:%ss") RETURN { [name]: true }`. This will return something like `[ { "14:05:08": true } ]`.